# After updating 12.04 at the next boot I get a black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: updates, login

I just updated my Ubuntu 12.04. Now I am stuck with a blinking cursor during start up.

Comment: In GRUB choose failsafe boot. Probably it will show which service freezes.

Comment: @ctheo Can you please tell me how to navigate to GRUB and choose failsafe boot?

Comment: When GRUB screen is on there is an option like "Ubuntu, Linux... (recovery mode)". Use up/down arrows to select it.

Comment: @ctheo I don't get the grub screen at all it just checks for the file system, net bios, and starting to mount network devices, and says waiting for 60 more seconds and then gets into blinking cursor....

Comment: @karel mine was not during installation but just updating the ubuntu.. It gets stuck... So I think the issue is different..

Comment: @ctheo usually after this... The login screen appears but not now..I tried to use ctrl + alt + del but it just cancel the loading and restarts into the same screen again...

Comment: In that case start with link 3. in that question: [If an update or something else caused your problem](http://askubuntu.com/a/162078).

Comment: @karel I couldn't find relevent information for my particular issue... As it tries to check file system, net bios and loads the network devices, gets loading and suddenly it gets into the blinking curser and when I cancel it. It says invoke rc.d failed and restarts the same routine again...

Comment: I don't believe that you could have read and understood all 29 answers to the linked question in less than 12 minutes.

Comment: @karel when I tried to get into safe mode and check it says I have 733 upgraded and 650 newly installed file. It asks whether should I upgrade. When I cancel it I am unable to load into the gui...

Comment: The update is not finished. My guess is that you probably did a release upgrade. Did you tried booting to an older kernel?

Comment: @ctheo I did a update to the latest update of 12.04 which I was intimidated by ubuntu When I started the update it was downloading the files and said it couldn't download few files and asked me to continue with the update and I did so after it said the updates are done and I need to restart for it take effect so I did as it said and now I am unable to load into gui at all. I am trying to update again by getting into tge grub and safe mode and install missing packages. It ask me do the same thing I did again. That is install 710 new files and delete 50 files. Hope this works fine. Just started.

Comment: @ctheo do you knoe how long does it approximately take for the update to be completed??

Comment: @ctheo trying to boot to older kernel doesn't work too. I end up at the sand state as mentioned initially

Comment: It will need a couple of hours to do release upgrade. It depends on your connection and hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the updates again by selecting recovery mode in the GRUB menu (under **Advanced Options for Ubuntu**, then the `dpkg` option (**Fix Broken Packages**) solved the issue by installing all the packages again. Now I can load into the GUI again.